# Color mapping of difference

Tags: color

I have two arrays `A` and `B`. I want to do color mapping of their difference `A - B`. So far, I am doing this:

```
1) calculate d = A - B
2) find min / max in d
3) linear mapping of d from (min, max) to (0, 1)
4) convert (0, 1) to color
```

The problem is, that sometimes, there are noise values in my data. For example, several values in `B` are too large (like 100 times bigger than the rest) and it leads to enormous difference and increased `min` or `max`. After mapping to (0, 1) all other values are "wiped". How can I solve this?

Comment: Are those noise values incorrect data or good data - i.e. do you want to "remove"/ignore them in result or do you want to include them?

Comment: @wondra I want to "ignore" them in a sort... ie. I want to show them as max / min error.

Comment: Are those data trending or of "continuous" function(read from a sensor)?

Comment: @wondra they are continuous in a way.. not read from sensor, but calculated from a discretized function with some added noise and compared with values calculated from the function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest two options:

1. use percentile instead of min/max (e.g. 95/5%, you need to experiment here), with linear mapping clamped to (0,1) range. To do so sort the `d` array and pick `(N - 1) * percentile + 1`th member as minimum/maximum, map as normal and clamp `r = Min(1.0, Max(0.0, r))` the results in (0,1) range
2. Use non linear mapping, for example the logarithmic scale is often used in scientific applications `d = log (d)`

The option 1 attempts to filter the data from erroneous values rather than displaying them, the quality heavily relies on on percentile settings, which is (input)data-dependent. The option 2 tries to use non-linear mapping in order to display meaningful values even for erroneous data, but requires users to understand logarithmic scale.

Comment: For #1 I would suggest a special color designating extreme values instead of clamping them. This would require passing a flag of some sort or using a sentinel value if the color mapping only takes one input.

Comment: @MooseBoys good idea, but it brings us to the original problem again - how do you tell which values are extreme(say 1000) and which ones are just a bit above(say 1.0001) percentile? You could combine it with #2, but it makes it even harder to read.